# How to correctly code Curl request in PHP with jsonrpc parameters?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I have a curl command that worls perfectly form the SSH shell, but cannot get it working with PHP Version 7.4.3.

I have tried several times using just about every example I can find on the Internet, all of them return a blank html page when run.

Here is the curl command (with user/pass and IP etc changed for obvious reasons);

```sh
curl \
  --user someuser:password \
  --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getinfo", "params": [] }' \
  -H 'content-type: text/plain;' \
  http://195.86.111.23:8223/
```

Can someone please educate me on how to turn this into something PHP can use?

I am currently testing with this code, but get an error "{"result":null,"error":{"code":-32600,"message":"Params must be an array"},"id":"curltest"} "

```
 $payload=array();
  $payload['jsonrpc']='1.0';
  $payload['id']='curltest';
  $payload['method']='getinfo';
  $payload['params']='[]';
  
  $payload=json_encode($payload);

  $ch = curl_init($url); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $pass);  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $res=curl_exec($ch);
  echo $res;
```

I have also tried using an automated tool here - https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ which seems to convert my curl command to PHP okay, but the page is empty on loading the provided code.

Comment: You want an array for `params`, not a string. Your code would produce `"params":"[]"`. Try `$payload['params'] = [];`. Even easier would be `$payload = ["jsonrpc" => "1.0", id => "curltest", "method" => "getinfo", "params" => [] ];`

Answer (score 0):

$payload = ["jsonrpc" => "1.0", id => "curltest", "method" => "getinfo", "params" => [] ];

Simple solution!